# A better input method for Sinhala?

Tags: ibus

I already tested out every Sinhala input method supported by [ibus](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ibus.1.html) on ElementaryOS(5.1), but everyone of these lack support for most Sinhala words in transliteration method like Google input tools(Now discontinued) does in windows. *Ex:- සිංහල(sinhala) සඳහා(sandahaa) ශ්‍රේණිය(shreniya) සංගීතය(sangeethaya)* 
**Is there any alternative Sinhala input method that is easier to use?**

Feels like this needs to be explained a liitle bit more, For an example in phonetic input "sin" in "sinhala" should be transliterated as "සිං" but every current input method does this as "සින්" which sounds same but is gramatically incorrect. Same goes for "nda" in "sandahaa" which should be "ඳ" but comes out as "න්ද"

Comment: Please advise which Linux distro is installed (Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.), and the release version number by clicking [edit] and adding it to the original question.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I don't know it is easier or useful to you, there are some. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Localization/Sinhalese . Mostly fcitx is useful to the Asian 2-byte characters, but I think your language has less characters than Chinese or Japanese, if you don't use a phonetic input, you don't need an input method. Japanese hiragana or Thai-ish 50-letter alphabet system would be easier by its own keyboard, this is all I know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTE

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ibus
```

Then restart the system

1. Open the “Language support” window (you can search for it)
   [Language support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OROG.png)
2. Choose “IBus” from the keyboard input method system under the language tab.
3. Click the “Install/Remove languages...” button and check the
   “Sinhala” language in the popup box and apply it.
   [Check Sinhala](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p179R.png)
4. Open the "settings" -> “Region & Language” window Click the “+” Plus sign on the Input sources section.
   [Region & Language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG6LB.png)
5. Choose “Sinhala” on the popup box to view available keyboard methods.
   [Add new keyboard input method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ojDj.png)
6. Then Select “Sinhala (wijesekera(m17n))” at the bottom. You are done.
   [Add wijesekara unicode input layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx7fe.png)

To Swithc keyboard =  [Win] + [Space bar]

සිංහල =  i+s+x+y+,

සඳහා = i+ [alt+ o] +y + d

ශ්‍රේණිය  = f+Y+`+a+K+s+h

සංගීතය = i+x+.+S+;+h

Sometime combined letters are not work in Libre office.

Ex. න්‍ද = k+[] + o

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and ibus(m17n) works well for me.

If ibus not installed, install it by these,

```
sudo apt-get install ibus ibus-gtk im-switch
```

And as m17n database contains Sinhala support, install it and ibus-m17n IME,

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n  m17n-db
```

Now in the keyboard settings you could find many options, choose one or more which fit to your needs. And default shortcut to switch input is `Super + Space`.

[image: sinhala linux ibus input keyboard settings]

According to the examples you have mentioned I think you are searching for an bit intelligent or probability-based tool which automatically choose the nearest dictionary word, like how Google Input did. I think ibus will not do that, as it requires to store a database of words.

I prefer using `Sinhala(singlish(m17n))` and following examples show how it print the words you mentioned.

| Typed keys | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `sinhala` | සින්හල |
| `siqhala` | සිංහල |
| `shreniya` | ශ්‍රෙනිය |
| `shrENiya` | ශ්‍රේණිය |
| `sangeethaya` | සන්ගෙඑතය |
| `saqgIthaya` | සංගීතය |